# PHP Mysql, to fetch a common values in an array within a single query

Tags: php, mysql

I'm having trouble in fetching common values in table, let me explain, i'm having table named as group_id, here there are 3 columns groupid, userid, id, in query i'm passing array of groupids now in the result i'm getting all the users in all the groups for which i'm passing, for that i'm using following code:

```
public function enlistusers($groupid) {
        $select = $this->_table->select();
        $select->from(array('a' => 'groups'),array());        
        $select->where ('a.groupid IN (?)',$groupid);
$rows = $this->_table->fetchAll($select)->toArray();
        if(empty($rows)) { return null; }
        return $rows;
}
```

After fetching all users i want the common users in all the groups for the groupid's which i'm passing, is there any mysql statement to do that within this query only to make it efficient?
Any suggention will be appreciated..
Thank you.

Comment: So you want to loop through each db item and put it up into an array?
if so you might want to look into a while loop and a function called: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php on this way you can add items in an array.

Comment: yeah we can put them into a single array that's good @Mike M, but how can check the common values?? see now i'm getting around 400 rows of results in a single array (here in $row for 4 groupid) and i've to check them depending on groupid and also have to select common users in all groups.

Comment: what do you actually mean with check the common values?
for example the array is: 1,2,3,3,3,2,4,4,5
give an example by the above "array" on what you want.

Comment: so consider your array list are userids then consider groupids as 101,102,103. if 3(userid) presents in all groups(mean 101,102,103) then i want that id in a separate array like wise for all the users @Mike u got??

Comment: so userid 3 => array(101,102,103) if I get you correctly
(AKA a nested array)

Comment: yeah @mike if the user 3 presents then i want him to be in separate array( not only one user all users list in an single array).

Comment: Why would you want to seperate userid's to arrays you can make a nested array yet what you want "in my beginners knowledge" is not really possible you can do something like this array(1 => array(usergroup[s]),2 => array(usergroup[s]))

Comment: Then how can i do it with using nested array can u help me?? @mike

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17396831/php-multidimensional-array-from-database-results might get you in your way...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the mysql class you're using, but the way to do what you want in pure mysql query is like this:

```
"SELECT *
FROM a as groups
WHERE a.groupid IN ".implode(',',$groupid)."
GROUP BY id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT a.groupid) = ".count($groupid);
```

change the "GROUP BY id" to something else, if you don't have the id column